# Is there a name for a phrase or proverb that multiple possible word-meanings but the same phrase-meaning?

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context, puns

I will start with my example to clarify the odd phrasing of my question.

> The die is cast.

Since both 'die' and 'cast' have two meanings, the phrase can be read in two ways:

1. The die [as in a game of dice] is cast [as in thrown].
2. The die [as in a metal tool‡] is cast [as in forged].

Both of these have the same meaning: something has been done that cannot be undone. (This coincidence has lead some to be confused about the original meaning, which is closer to the first I describe).

Are there other examples of phrases that so neatly have two paths to the same meaning by replacing multiple words? If so, do they have a name (so that I may look up more  )?

‡ casting is not the best way to make a die, but the meaning holds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're describing a special case of a special case. Let's start with the less special case.

Words like 'die' and 'cast' that have multiple meanings are called ***[ambiguous](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/ambiguous)***, which means:

> (Of language) open to more than one interpretation; having a double meaning.

Given that its constituent words are ambiguous, your example of "the die is cast" can thus be said to be an ***ambiguous proverb***. This phrase even has some currency, evidenced [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=rfWFu5C-tL0C&pg=PA69&lpg=PA69&dq=ambiguous%20proverbs&source=bl&ots=2FJWXnxZWp&sig=rQes19vqrIZNfXIvoBldrUJw5P8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1lbbdmqnOAhUKMyYKHc2cC60Q6AEIKTAD#v=onepage&q=ambiguous%20proverbs&f=false) and [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/30035098).

Now, ambiguity can be caused by the word having multiple meanings, in which case it is called ***[lexical ambiguity](http://grammar.about.com/od/il/g/lexicalambiguityterm.htm)***, or it can be caused by there being multiple ways to group the words in the sentence, in which case it is called ***[syntactic ambiguity](http://grammar.about.com/od/rs/g/syntacticambiguityterm.htm)***.

Your example of "the die is cast" is an example of lexical ambiguity. A few other examples of lexically ambiguous proverbs are mentioned [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=rfWFu5C-tL0C&pg=PA69&lpg=PA69&dq=ambiguous%20proverbs&source=bl&ots=2FJWXnxZWp&sig=rQes19vqrIZNfXIvoBldrUJw5P8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1lbbdmqnOAhUKMyYKHc2cC60Q6AEIKTAD#v=onepage&q=ambiguous%20proverbs&f=false):

> - ***A good husband makes a good wife.***
> - ***Good masters make good servants.***

These are ambiguous because "make" can be interpreted as both "bring about" and "amount to". Notice that, unlike in your example, resolving the ambiguity *does* result in different proverbial meanings.

Now, your example of "the die is cast" is a special case where the ambiguity in the constituent words does not scotch its figurative meaning. In that sense, you might *not* want to call it an ambiguous proverb, since regardless of the disambiguation, you arrive at the same figurative meaning.

Instead, to coin a phrase, you might call it a ***bistable proverb***, where ***[bistable](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/bistable)*** means:

> having two stable states.

In a way, a hearer who encounters this proverb can vacillate between the two literal disambiguations without it affecting the figurative meaning. The figurative meaning is thus *bistable*.

---

Finally, your example of the (bistable) proverb "the die is cast" is very similar to examples of so-called ***[eggcorns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn)***, defined by Wikipedia as:

> In linguistics, an **eggcorn** is an idiosyncratic substitution of a word or phrase for a word or words that sound similar or identical in the speaker's dialect.... The new phrase introduces a meaning that is different from the original but plausible in the same context, such as "old-timers' disease" for "Alzheimer's disease".... Eggcorns often involve replacing an unfamiliar, archaic, or obscure word with a more common or modern word ("baited breath" for "bated breath").

In an eggcorn, words are substituted in a phrase for similar sounding words. The result is an expression that, although different in literal meaning from the intended expression, has roughly the same "figurative" meaning. For example, "old-timer's disease" for "Alzheimer's disease".

Your example of "the die is cast"/"the die is cast" might be considered a limiting case of eggcorn, one in which phonologically identical *and* orthographically identical words are substituted. The result is that the literal meanings are different, but the figurative meaning is the same.

Comment: Applause, great answer Silenus.

Comment: Beautiful, just what I was looking for (and more). I love 'bistable proverb' as a term, as a dovetailing of my love of physics and of language.